# Flag "options" disappear?

Tags: support, flagging

Not that I'm a "flag happy" person but if somethings only been flagged once, why are the flagging "options" a lot of times cut in half. I've noticed there's normally only 3 of the 6 flags "options" available to a second person if they wanted to flag.

For clarity by flag options I mean these:

- it is spam
- it is offensive, abusive, or hate speech
- it is a duplicate...
- it should be closed for another reason...
- it is very low quality
- other (needs ♦ moderator attention)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on your reputation. For example, once you are able to Vote to Close, the `duplicate` and `closed for another reason` options disappear! If it's put into one of those queues already, then those two options disappear for those without the privilege.

As well, you won't have those two options on answers that you flag. The way they generate flags, selecting certain items lets other community users decide what to do with them (i.e. fix it up or vote to delete). Once it's in there, there is no point in having a second flag of certain types on it.

I can't go into the specifics of how each flag works and affects the users though, but know that they are getting taken care of.